# Am I better off splitting an elaborate mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Assuming the case of a `/login` API, where, for a matching set of credentials, a user object from the collection should be returned, which approach would be more performant:

1) One model with projection queries:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name        : String,
  email       : String,
  dob         : Number,
  phone       : Number,
  gender      : String,
  location    : Object, // GeoJSON format {type: 'Point', geometry: { lat: '23.00', lng: '102.23' }}
  followers   : [UserSchema],
  following   : [UserSchema],
  posts       : [PostSchema],
  groups      : [GroupSchema]
  // ... and so on
});
```

2) Split models:

```
var UserMinimalSchema = new Schema({
  name        : String,
  email       : String,
  phone       : Number,
  location    : Object, 
});

var UserDetailSchema = new Schema({
  dob         : Number,
  gender      : String,
  followers   : [UserSchema],
  following   : [UserSchema],
  posts       : [PostSchema],
  groups      : [GroupSchema]
  // ... and so on
});
```

---

Let's say:

1. For a logged-in user, only `id`, `name`, `email`, `phone` and `location` are to be returned.
2. The first model will use a projection query to return the properties in (1).
3. In the second case, only the `UserMinimalSchema` would be used to query the entire document.
4. Essentially both queries return exactly the same amount of data as mentioned in (1).
5. Assume that average user object is ~16MB limit and there are 1 Million records.

If someone performed such a test/links to documentation, it would be of great help to see how much it will matter to split or not.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use split models:

1. You'll have to perform a population query everytime you want to look all of the user's data
2. You're increasing your data storage (you now will have to reference the user in your user details schema.
3. When Mongo will go do a lookup, it will find references to model instances and only extract data that you've specified in your projection query anyways. It will not load the entire object into memory unless you specify that in your query.

Comment: I am suspecting (3) to be the case too. I don't understand (1), the properties in `UserMinimalSchema` are not present in `UserDetailSchema`? If you can provide links which prove (3) it will be of great help, as I expect that to happen but couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal you're right. I thought you wanted to store some details in both schemas, but upon closer inspection you're splitting them up uniquely. However this raises another con because if you want all of the user's information then you have to perform an extra step to populate the user. Updating answer with more thoughts.